# When editing a textarea, how can I prevent the containing div from scrolling to it?

Tags: scroll, textarea, overflow, containers, hidden

I am developing a website where users can create textareas and move them around as they like inside a container div with overflow:hidden - corresponding to a piece of paper.

My problem arises when a textarea is positioned at the edge of the container (ie. only some of the textarea is visible). When the user types in the textarea and the caret moves outside of the visible part, the container scrolls to show all of the textarea.

Try it out by typing something after the semicolon in the textarea in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PG8SU/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Some other text</p>
    <textarea>Type:</textarea>
</div>

.container {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 50px; 
    left:100px;
}
textarea {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    left:250px;
    width:100px;
    top:200px;
}
```

This seems like default behavior in most browsers, like Chrome and IE. I would like to avoid any scrolling of the container, and just have the textarea stay partly visible even if the user types in it.

Does anyone have an idea as to how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this a bit, I believe it's not entirely possible to do this in a nice way.

It's an odd use-case, for sure, and usually you're better off setting the width of the text area to be $(".container").width() - $("textarea").position().left, but! If you do need the text outside the container, and you do need it to overflow, this will kind of work:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
    $(".container").scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
}).keydown(function() {
    $(".container").scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
});
```

I ran this in your jsfiddle, and it causes the screen to flicker when you type, but it ultimately disables the scrolling. It's not ideal, but it's the best I think you're gonna find.